# DocuSign SOAP - How to add external link to Envelope and email bounces

Tags: docusignapi

Newbie questions:

1. How to add external link URL with custom text to the Envelop when create envelope by calling DocuSign SOAP/DSAPI CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates? The goal is: the DocuSign email sent to recipient will have informational link in the email message body in addition to standard "REVIEW DOCUMENT" link.

Is it done by setting the Customer Field "#HREF_TheURL" in the request body "/" segment in the SOAP request body? How to set the properties associated to it, such as text, Tooltip, url value, formating...etc?

2. to handle the bounced back email, is it sufficient to tell from the response body message -" value "AutoResponded"?

Thank you,
CT

Comment: First question: why do you want to use the SOAP API? It is NOT updated with new eSignature features. And it doesn't support OAuth either. The eSignature REST API is highly recommended for new eSignature integrations with DocuSign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. It's a high security risk.

Let me explain.

Using DocuSign for phishing would become very easy if you add the capability for anyone to add links to the DocuSign official emails. They may be able to fool the end-users to do things that they shouldn't be doing (like entering their passwords in the scammer's website).

If you need a link you may need to send your own emails.

Comment: Thanks Inbar.  That makes sense. We will use template attached to the Envelope instead.